# Is "as" okay in the sentence?

Tags: grammar, writing

I'm writing a script. Here's part of a scene:

The plane is accelerating down the runway. Tim (he's seriously scared of flying) is desperately trying to calm himself. But **as** the plane takes off —

TIM: Oh my god! Oh my god!

Is **as** correct in the sentence? Does the sentence work?

Comment: It's easier for us to answer these kinds of questions if you explain your thinking.  Do you think *as* should be there?  Why or why not?

Comment: I think "as" should be there, but I'm not completely sure, so would like to know if the sentence is okay in the context.

Answer (score 1):

"As" is fine for normal English.

You should look at other scripts to see how stage or camera directions are written.  There is a style to this that is different from other types of writing. Stage directions should give directions, not descriptions.:

> (The plane accelerates. Tim desperately tries to calm himself. The plane takes off)
>
> Tim: Oh my God!